# How to get Unique device id in phonegap ? for GCM

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I am making phonegap based android application. I am trying to register my device to register on GCM pushNotification plugin. but it not running properly, is throws Class Not found error.
So i want to know how to get unique device id for registering on GCM

Comment: Getting the device id and getting a "Class Not Found" error (do you mean `ClassNotFoundException`?) are two different things. Try solving one problem at a time and add the code that throws the error.

Comment: @suraj mahajan Could you provide a stack trace of the ClassNotFoundException? As CurlyCorvus said you have two different issues here, and the title really only matches one of those questions.